# Copy folder from Resource to Document in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

i have one subfolder in Resources with name SketchImages which contains 300 PNG images, what i need to do is on the startup of my app copy this folder in document folder of iphone sdk, i am trying the following code with no luck

```
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] init];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory     
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SketchImages"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath];

if (success)
{
    return;
}else
{
    NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB"];
    //[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath: documentDBFolderPath attributes:nil];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath           
                          error:&error];
}
```

any help will be highly appriciated

Comment: why you want to copy all the images to document directory??
It will increase your app size in iphone...

Comment: i am working on a drawing book, i need to do this

Comment: What error returned when you call copyItemAtPath?

Comment: NSArray *paths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil]];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] init];
NSArray *documentpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(    
NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentpaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];

NSError *err;

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] 
toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:err];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong subfolder name:

```
NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SketchImages"];
```

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan You "have one subfolder in Resources with name SketchImages", and you are trying to copy the subfolder named "DB". Since you don't have a Resources subfolder named "DB", your code does not work.